# Magento: What is the most efficient way to set all configurable products to be in stock?

Tags: magento

After updating all products with stock levels, what is the best way to set all configurable products to be in stock?
By best way, I mean quickest with least load on server.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say, how to do this programatically!

Answer (score 6):

In your `Catalog > Manage Products` view:

**Select 'Configurable' from the dropdown in the grid:**

[image: order grid view config select]

**Click on 'Select All' in the grid table header:**

[image: select all]

**Select "Update Attributes" from the drop-down menu at the top of the grid and click "Submit":**

[image]

**Finally, from the next screen you can perform a mass inventory update. Click on the 'Inventory' tab to the left side of the screen and set them all to "in stock" and "enabled".**

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say - 'programatically'! Hurts to see how much effort has been put into the answer! But I am sure someone else will benefit from the answers posted here...

Comment: you have your answer, go see what is behind the action in the related controller ..

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version, from the admin interface you can select all products of the type configurable, then `Actions -> Update Attributes -> Inventory`.

Example (see last option): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0vf.png

It's either that or writing your own script, which would more than likely do the exact same thing (if not be less effective by forgetting a validate call or something, heaven forbid it leaves around orphaned DB entries by mistake which would lead you into a world of pain at some point or another) in terms of load/time and effectiveness. And truthfully, I can't imagine it taking very long unless your **configurable product count** is in the tens of thousands, or your servers specs are very poor, in which case it probably wouldn't be running Magento to begin with.

**EDIT:**
This should let you do it programatically. **Note though**, Magentos facility of "Stock Item" has changed a lot throughout it's lifespan, so be sure to test on your version to ensure it works first.

```
// Get all products with a type_id of configurable                                                                                                                                                                                          
$configurable_products = 
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');                                                                                                                                                                                          


foreach ($configurable_products as $configurable_product) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
  $configurable_product->load();                                                                                                                                                                                                            

  // Set is in stock attribute to 1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  $configurable_product->getStockItem()->setIsInStock(1);                                                                                                                                                                                   

  try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    $configurable_product->getStockItem()->save();                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  } catch (Exception $e) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    // Failed to save for some reason...                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Edited my original answer to address that as well.